# perl excel parse and modify the same worksheet

Tags: perl, excel

I need to compare my XLS file with another one and modify the first (some cells) one accordingly.
I need to do it crossplatform so I use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser

Here is the subroutine I have so far

```
sub find_occurrences
{
my $xlsname   = $_[0];
my $pattern   = $_[1];
my $parser    = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $workbook  = $parser->parse($xlsname);
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0) || die("$@$!");
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();   
for my $row ( 0 .. $row_max ) {         
    $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 );
    next if (!$cell);    
    if($cell->value() =~ m/$pattern/i )
    {
        print "Order found ",$cell->value(),"\n";   
        $worksheet->AddCell( $row, 1, "Shop" );     
    }       

}
}
```

http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/SaveParser.pm

Seems like example, bu I got this error:
Can't locate object method "AddCell" via package "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet" at ./test.pl line 153.

It is this one line

$worksheet->AddCell( $row, 1, "Shop" );

I tried even add

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook;
```

I'm new to perl and i wasn't able to google something helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mixed up some code from `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` and `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser`

The problem are the `parse()`, `Parse()`  methods. 
Unfortuntly the interface is not very transparant. If you call

`$parser->parse(...)`

you get an `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook` object, but if you use

`$parser->Parse(...)`

you get an `use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser::Workbook` object.

**That is what you need!**.

Here is my example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

find_occurrences ('Mappe1.xls', qr/.*/);

sub find_occurrences {
    my ($xlsname, $pattern) = @_;

    my $parser    = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
    my $workbook  = $parser->Parse($xlsname);
    my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0) || die("$@$!");

    print "Workbook is a :". ref($workbook). "\n"; 

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();   
    for my $row ( 0 .. $row_max ) {         
        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 );
        next if (!$cell);    
        if($cell->value() =~ m/$pattern/i )
        {
            print "Order found ",$cell->value(),"\n";   
            $worksheet->AddCell($row, 1, "Shop" );     
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to add the it's need to add $workbook->SaveAs($_[0]); at the end to save changes